# How do i convert a String to a List<Map<String,String>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which contains several keys and values, which are then mapped into a DataTable to be displayed.

```
  List<Map<String, String>> listOfColumns = [
    {"Name": "John", "Number": "1", "State": " "},
    {"Name": "Brad", "Number": "2", "State": " "},
    {"Name": "Ryan", "Number": "3", "State": " "},
    {"Name": "Grant", "Number": "4", "State": " "},


  ];
```

Now, i want the data in the data table to be saved. So I simply used the File IO system i created an asynchronous function called _save() and _read(), in _save() i converted listOfColumns to a string.

```
_read() async {
    try {
      final directory = await  getExternalStorageDirectory();
      final file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.txt');


      text = await file.readAsString();

    } catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't read file");
    }
  }

  _save() async {
    final directory = await  getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.txt');
    final List<Map<String, String>> data = listOfColumns;
    await file.writeAsString(data.toString());
    print('saved');

  }
```

Now when it comes to reading the data from the file, here's the thing - How do i actually turn the variable text back into `List<Map<String,String>>`? Im totally lost on how to achieve this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would check out a package called [localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage). It stores data as a JSON file so you can store data easier than a text (.txt) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually save it as [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in the first place (using [`jsonEncode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) and then you can easily convert it back:

```dart
Future<void> _save() async {
  ...
  final jsonString = jsonEncode(listOfColumns);
  await file.writeAsString(jsonString);
}
```

Now, you can easily load your data using [`jsonDecode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html):

```dart
Future<void> _read() async {
  ...
  final decoded = jsonDecode(await file.readAsString()) as List;
  listOfColumns = decoded.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
       .map((map) => map.cast<String, String>()).toList();
}
```

Comment: Spot on! however, when i call _read(), it shows couldn't read file.. any idea why would that be?

Comment: @portableCoder What does `print(e)` show you (I mean printing the error caught by the `try-catch` I left out of my answer)?

Comment: @portableCoder I think that I know why this might be happening. The type cast I included previously is incorrect. I updated `_read` in my answer accordingly.

Comment: As a sidenote, how do you figure out the proper casts to more complicated types??

Comment: @portableCoder `jsonDecode` will always return `dynamic`, either `List<dynamic>` or `Map<String, dynamic>`. You can only cast when you are completely sure that every element has that type. I do not know all JSON types, but I would assume that they are `bool`, `String`, `num`, and maybe `int`/`double`. You would have to do some testing or check the documentation/implementation of the decoding for that. Glad I was able to help you.